# Show Jenkins Parallel Tasks in Report like Stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

so I managed to get parallel build execution in a Jenkins pipeline running two jobs: "Unit Tests" and "E2E Tests", but the only way I could make it work, is inside a single "Testing" stage as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Testing') {
            steps {
                parallel("Unit Tests": {
                    echo "Running Tests"
                    build 'Jenkins Job 1'
                },
                "E2E Tests": {
                    build 'Jenkins Job2'
                }
                )
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                parallel("first": {
                    echo "Open a ticket to deploy"
                },
                        "second": {
                            echo "Confirm when ticket was approved"
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently this results in a build report that looks like:
[image]

Our goal is to get a report that looks like:
[image]

So, how do we get the two build jobs in separate stage views, while keeping them running in parallel? I was not able to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change it to something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def tests = [:]

                    stage("Unit Tests") {
                        tests["Unit Tests"] = {
                            build 'Jenkins Job 1'
                        }
                    }
                    stage("E2E Tests") {
                        tests["E2E Tests"] = {
                            build 'Jenkins Job 2'
                        }
                    }
                    parallel tests
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not working, I get error `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 6: Expected a step @ line 6, column 17.
                   def tests = [:]
                   ^

WorkflowScript: 7: Expected a step @ line 7, column 17.
                   tests["Unit Tests"] = {
                   ^

WorkflowScript: 11: Expected a step @ line 11, column 17.
                   tests["E2E Tests"] = {
                   ^`

Comment: Line 6 is where def is

Comment: Not working :( `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during canonicalization: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep`

Comment: Thanks, I updated your answer to put parallel inside. It is building now, but so far the Stage View hasnt updated yet - it only shows "Testing" and "Deploy" stages, doesnt show the indvidual steps Unit Tests and E2E Tests progress.. which is what I want to see. So ideally if we can refactor the above example to run two stages in parallel, so that I can see them progressing in Stage View, would be great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166982/discussion-between-carmageddon-and-yorammi).

Comment: I looked around, doesnt look like our corporate Jenkins has Blue Ocean plugin installed :( Enjoy your weekend and looking forward for a workaround on Sunday/Monday :)

Comment: Thank you @yorammi, now it shows the new stages nicely, but two problems: 1) It still shows the encapsulating 'Tests' stage, as if it were a first standalone test. 2) The run time displayed for 'Unit Tests' and 'E2E Tests' stages is about 50ms or something, not the actual time it takes the parallel jobs to run. Can we fix that?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution for 1). Maybe you should name it 'Tests:' or something similar that will indicate that the following stages are sub-items of it (again, in BlueOcean it will be shown better).
About 2) it is very odd. Is it the same after the job is done (refresh the page)?

Comment: about 1) maybe the overall stage should be called 'tests' and the sub-stages should be called 'tests - unit tests' and 'tests - E2E tests'

Comment: I can live with 1 for now. Yes times are still showing 128, 43 and 51 ms for 'Tests', 'Unit Tests' and 'E2E Tests' respectively after a refresh.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat